Can backtrack be enabled for Aurora PostgreSQL or just Aurora MySQL?
I was trying to set up Aurora because I'd heard about the easy point-in-time recovery with Backtrack. But looking closer, that seems to only be available with Aurora MySQL. Is that true or am I just bad at Googling?

PITR is an Aurora feature so it should available in PostgreSQL as well. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-pitr.html
While Backtracking is a feature for Aurora MySQL. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Managing.Backtrack.html

No. As for now it is only supported for MySQL db engine.
[...] 'Backtrack is not available for Aurora PostgreSQL.'
See: related aws docs
